# convert string to date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I convert `YYYY-MM-DD` (`2012-08-17`) to a date in SQL Server?

I don't see this format listed on the help page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 28):

I think style no. 111 (Japan) should work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-08-17', 111)
```

And if that doesn't work for some reason - you could always just strip out the dashes and then you have the totally reliable ISO-8601 format (`YYYYMMDD`) which works for **any** language and date format setting in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('2012-08-17', '-', '') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: is there no way of specifying the format like 'ddmmyyyy'? having a random number just seems really horrible

Comment: I think that's for going in the opposite direction - from a date to a string.  There doesnt appear to be an equivalent

Comment: Using styles in `CONVERT` is only relevant when convert _from_ a date or time to a character string. When converting a date or time _to_ a character string styles are irrelevant.

Comment: But why strip the dashes? Which versions of SQL Server don't support that? It works perfectly on all of the versions I have on hand, admittedly not many that old.

Comment: @SilverbackNet: try `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN; SELECT CAST('2018-06-25' AS DATETIME)` and you'll see that this ends in an **error** - while if you use the `20180625` without the dashes, it works (regardless of language / regional settings)

Answer (score 6):

This will do the trick:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
```

Comment: What is the third parameter, and its optional ?

Comment: @daniele3004 it's the format that is returned, you can see all the different formats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. Here's what I was able to do to get a date range in a "where" clause (a modification of marc_s's answer):

```
where cast(replace(foo.TestDate, '-', '') as datetime) 
      between cast('20110901' as datetime) and
              cast('20510531' as datetime)
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

if you datatype is datetime of the table.col , then database store data contain two partial : 1 (date) 2 (time)

Just in display data use convert or cast.

Example:

```
create table #test(part varchar(10),lastTime datetime)
go

insert into #test (part ,lastTime )
values('A','2012-11-05 ')

insert into #test (part ,lastTime )
values('B','2012-11-05 10:30')


go

select * from #test 

A   2012-11-05 00:00:00.000
B   2012-11-05 10:30:00.000

select part,CONVERT (varchar,lastTime,111) from #test

A   2012/11/05
B   2012/11/05

select part,CONVERT (varchar(10),lastTime,20) from #test 

A   2012-11-05
B   2012-11-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SAP_TO_DATETIME(@input VARCHAR(14))
RETURNS datetime
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret datetime
    DECLARE @dtStr varchar(19)

    SET @dtStr = substring(@input,1,4) + '-' +  substring(@input,5,2) + '-' + substring(@input,7,2)
                + ' ' + substring(@input,9,2) + ':' + substring(@input,11,2) + ':' + substring(@input,13,2);        

    SET @ret = COALESCE(convert(DATETIME, @dtStr, 20),null);
    RETURN @ret
END
```