# Removing dots from a date in a url

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following URL in a table and I am given the responsibility to develop a script to remove the dots around the date. 
For example:

The Date: `2013.01.20` should be read like the following in the url:

```
http://local.website.net/doc/q?file=5448245&date=20130829&ref=65457
```

Note the dots for http://local.website.net should not be removed.

How I can get started on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert string to date in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277674/convert-string-to-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @doc varchar(500) = 'http://local.website.net/doc/q?file=5448245&date=2013.08.29&ref=65457'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@doc,0,CHARINDEX('date=',@doc))+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@doc,CHARINDEX('date=',@doc),LEN(@doc)),'.','')
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22746)